# Scala - Initialize an empty mutable SynchronizedHashMap

Tags: scala, hashmap, synchronized

From what I understand, we can initialize an empty mutable HashMap as

```
var keyCountsMap :scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any, Int] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any, Int]()
```

But how do I initialize this HasMap as synchronized ?
I tried

```
var keyCountsMap :scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedMap[Any, Int] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any, Int]()
```

but it I get the following error:

> type mismatch;  found   : scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any,Int]
>   required: scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedMap[Any,Int]

Comment: If you want a thread-safe map, use [concurrent.TrieMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mixin the SynchronizedMap ( [deprecated in 2.11](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedMap) )

```
    var keyCountsMap = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Any, Int]() with scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedMap[Int, Int]
```

Comment: I need a solution that is scala version agnostic.

Comment: @HaseebJaved that won't happen. If something is deprecated, chances are, it will not exist in a future version.

Comment: @wheaties yeah that is why I need a solution that is not deprecated in version 2.11

Comment: @HaseebJaved you realize that `SynchronizedMap` itself is deprecated. Chose a different collection.

Comment: If you don't want to use the SynchronizedMap (which was in the original question), you can consider http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation you will see:

> This class should be used as a **mixin**. It synchronizes the Map
>   functions of the class into which it is mixed in.

and

> Synchronization via traits is deprecated as it is inherently
>   unreliable. Consider **java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap** as an
>   alternative.